# Is Bohm's Implicate and Explicate order similar to Schopenhauer's Will and Representation?

Tags: metaphysics, schopenhauer

Bohm considered [Implicate order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicate_and_explicate_order) to be fundamental and holistic, while Explicate order was only derivative.  Similarly to Schopenhauer who had his principium individuationis, and considered Representation to emerge from the Will.

Do you know about any connection between them? Are there any more similarities?

Comment: At this level of vagueness you can analogize it to pretty much any philosophy with some "true world" behind the appearances, starting with Plato's. And Plato is probably a better fit since he was a rationalist, like Bohm and unlike Schopenhauer.